# Not able to click link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

Hi my delete button which is a LinkButton doesn't work while it took a long time for me to type the code for it to work but I don't know what's wrong with it, please help. Here is some code for it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class fileuploader : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        show_data();
    }

    private void show_data()
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/data/"));
        FileInfo[] r = d.GetFiles();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("path");
        for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow row=dt.NewRow();
            row["path"] = "~/data/" + r[i].Name;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if  (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string path = "~/data/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "" + Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(path));
            Response.Write("Save Succesfully");
            show_data();
        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        file.Delete(MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
        Response.Write("File Deleted Succesfully");
        show_data();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've added the missing language tags but I'm not 100% sure whether they're right so please correct them otherwise. BTW, the `enter code here` is just a place-holder, you aren't meant to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have added Onclick="LinkButton1_Command" in your Linkbutton control.

Comment: Thanks a lot but where should I put it as Onclick="LinkButton1_Command" and here is a part of the source code that I think it should go in but where  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("path") %>' OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be OnClientClick="LinkButton1_Command" with something else because I tried it and that's what another guy seems like he is telling me but I'm not sure.

Comment: OnClick will work on server side , OnClientClick will execute on client side before control passed to server. 

Generally programmers use onclientclick to validate the controls like textbox,etc.